# scan folder for kind of file java

Tags: java, csv

Is it possible if I have a path, to get a list of the filenames with only file extentions csv or txt?

For example, in path c:\files, I have following files:

```
text1.txt
text2.txt
csvfile.csv
csvfile2.csv
```

What is the best practice to get list from path folder with java? Thanks.
I don't know what a keyword for googling.. I have no reference.. at least I have a reference or keyword for I googling thanks.

Comment: I don't know what a keyword for googling.. I have no reference.. at least I have a reference or keyword for I googling thanks

Comment: `dirFile.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.matches(".*\\.(txt|csv)"))`

Comment: Just type your questions title into google and you get your answer. You haven’t made any effort

Answer (score -1):

Bash script can do this. like below:
find $directory -type f -name "*.csv"

Or google around "find files with suffix"